# plupload filter for pdf files only not working as expected

Tags: jquery, pdf, jquery-file-upload, plupload

i'm trying to set a filter for accepting PDF files only in the plupload file dialog.
my code:

```
var mime_types = {title : "PDF Files", extensions : "pdf"};

var uploader = new plupload.Uploader({
                runtimes : 'html5,flash,silverlight,html4',
                browse_button : id_button,
                container: id_container,
                url : '/uploader/xUpload.php',
                flash_swf_url : 'js/Moxie.swf',
                silverlight_xap_url : 'js/Moxie.xap',

                filters : {
                    max_file_size : '30mb',
                    mime_types: [
                        mime_types
                    ]
                }
});
```

This should work - but the file dialog still accepts "All files".
Any ideas?

thanks

PS: i just found out that the original example also not works as expected (i'm using firefox and the dialog also says "all files")

Answer (score 1):

You use 'html5' as first runtime. 'html5' does not support filtering file types by file extensions, only mime types. To make this work you should call this before the current code:

```
mOxie.Mime.addMimeType("application/pdf,pdf");
```

See [this thread](http://www.plupload.com/docs/Frequently-Asked-Questions) for more info about it.

Comment: The newer syntax seems to be `moxie.core.utils.Mime.addMimeType`

Comment: @fnagel's response the correct one for version 2.3.6 of plupload. Many thanks. The FAQ on the plupload site is very out of date.